# G++ build exe file in specific directory

Tags: c++, g++

I was lately using SDL and now i want to put the .exe file in a specific directory so it looks cleaner, somebody knows how to do that?

Comment: Use the `-o` parameter and supply the output path

Comment: Read your compilers documentation. It's all in there. Make an effort yourself for crying out loud. Btw; SDL has *nothing* to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling with `g++`, `gcc`, or many other similar compilers, you specify the output file with the `-o` flag.

For example, to set the output file as `foo.exe` in the parent directory, you would call `g++` like this:

```bash
g++ [other options/source files here] -o ../foo.exe
```